# Determine the number of child processes created by fork()

Tags: c, linux

We have this code in C, it creates child processes.

The question is how many processes are created ?
I calculated 8 processes, my friend 12. Who is right ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int i;

  for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
      fork();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My hyphotesis is that the stack is copied from parent to child and every child resumes parent's code in the same point where it stopped.

Comment: If you don't want to calculate it, print something after every `fork` when it returns a number greater than 0

Comment: Why don't you just run it and check?

Comment: You have that hypothesis and yet must have ignored it to get the answer 8...

Comment: I tried . And i get that (a part the main parent process) 15 processes are created . Is it correct ?

Comment: @Yabatter95 Is it correct?  Who knows - it's your code, you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Since `fork()` returns `0` in the child process, by printing a line for every child process that is created by `fork()` you can simply count the number of children that were created:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (!fork()) {
        printf("child created\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very constructive downvote.